# Inventing a suitable infix operator symbol for liftM

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

When working with monadic expressions in Haskell, the use of `liftM`'s (even in infix position) often seems quite unaesthetic and verbose to me.

Most other monadic primitives (`>>=`, `>>`) and even `liftM`'s *pure pendant* `$` are infix operators. This makes me think why there is no operator symbol for monadic lifting.

Do you have reasonable, consistent suggestions for an operator symbol (or why there shouldn't be one)?
(I thought of `>-` and `-<` (shifting the monad through a function), but they seem to have different meanings in the context of arrows.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider something like `<$` (`<<$` for `liftM2`, `<<<$` for `liftM3`).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `<$>` operator from Control.Applicative.

EDIT: Unfortunately `<$>` only works for some Monads which are instances of Applicative. Defining some `instance Monad m => Applicative m` is not possible as this would overlap with the existing Applicative instances IO, Maybe and [].

Comment: All monads are applicative. Creating an instance of Applicative for a monad is as simple as declaring `a <$> f = a >>= (return . f)` and `(<*>) = ap`.

Comment: By the way, `(liftM2 f) x y` is equivalent to `f <$> x <*> y`. Ditto for `liftM3`, etc. Just keep adding `<*>`.

Comment: `"Defining some instance Monad m => Applicative m is not possible as this would overlap with the existing Applicative instances IO, Maybe and []."` Maybe I'm not getting it, but even if you could, you wouldn't need to because you already have `<$>` at your disposal for these types.

Answer (score 1):

Since `liftM == fmap` and `(.) == fmap` for functions (the `((->) r)` instance of `Functor`), I suggest hiding `(.)` from `Prelude` and defining:

```
import Prelude hiding ((.))
import Control.Monad.Instances () -- import Functor instance for functions

infixr 9 .    
(.) :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
(.) = fmap
```

Examples:

```
foo = (\x -> x ^ 2) . (\x -> x + 1)
(+1) . [1, 2, 3]
someIO =<< read . getLine -- more useful in do notation because of following
someIO . read =<< getLine -- equivalent to above but uses different instance
```